# Issue in upgrading in-app purchase subscription android(Error while retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01)

Tags: android, in-app-billing, in-app-subscription

I was able to upgrade the subscription using license tester email, but suddenly it stops working. I am using poration mode **BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.IMMEDIATE_AND_CHARGE_PRORATED_PRICE** for upgrading and **BillingFlowParams.ProrationMode.DEFERRED** for downgrade. Now I am not able to downgrade or upgrade the subscription. The error I got is `Error while retrieving information from server. DF-DFERH-01`. I am using the latest billing library version 4.0.0. I am not able to perform any testing due to the error.

Answer (score 0):

So I had this exact same issue, for me the solution was that the PurchaseToken I stored in a SQL-database was set as VARCHAR(100) and the length of the purchaseToken is always longer.

The response from Google Lib is still just wrong, as it returns SERVICE_UNAVAILABLE when its the purchaseToken thats wrong.

Anyways, if it helps anyone thats having this issue, double check your purchaseToken :).